# For loop skipping login verfication

Tags: python-3.x

The for loop is skipping over the if statements when the loop is complete or at least thats what I think it is doing. Let me know what I need to revise. The dictionary has usernames and passwords stored in from inputted new users.

```
import json

users = {}
def create_new_login():
    new_username = (input("Please enter a username: "))
    new_password = (input("Please enter a password: "))
    filename = 'login.json'

    if new_username in users.keys():
        input("Please input a new username")
    elif new_password in users.values():
        input("Please input a new password")
    else:
        users.update({new_username : new_password})
        with open(filename, 'a') as file_object:
            json.dump(users, file_object)

def check_username():
    """Checks username and password"""

    #User inputs username and password
    username_input = input("Please enter your username: ")
    for key in users.keys(): #Checks username and password
        if username_input == key:
            check_password()
        else: 
            print("Incorrect login")

def check_password():
    password_input = input("Please enter your password: ")

    for value in users.values():
        if password_input == value:
            print("Welcome back " + users)

welcome = input("Are you a new user?(yes or no):  ")

if welcome == 'yes':
    create_new_login()

if welcome == 'no':
    check_username()
```

I expect if the username entered is in the dictionary then it will run the `check_password` function and do the same task for the password. But upon completion it will say "Welcome back " + the username inputted. Also if someone could explain how instead of using users for the welcome back I could use the password given to find the key for that value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You've written the json file but are not reading from it. Every time you re-run the program you start at the top and initialize `users = {}`. Put a `print` statement in the `for` loop and you will find that `users.keys()` is `dict_keys([])` is empty. And this makes the `for` loop "skip over" `if` because it fails the condition. What you ought to do is to read from the json file and then check the condition.